# How to use redirect option with uBlock Origin Static network filtering?

Tags: browser, website, adblock, ublock-origin, ublock

Just to understand the concept. Say, there is an image on a web page and I want to replace that image with a "neutered" resource. Say, there is a site **example.com**, and there is an image on a web page **example.com/files/badimage.gif**. I want to replace it with something else.

So far I tried:

```
||example.com/files/$image,redirect=2x2-transparent.png,domain=github.com
||example.com/files/badimage.gif$image,redirect=2x2-transparent.png,domain=github.com
||example.com/files/badimage.gif,redirect=2x2-transparent.png,domain=github.com
```

Neither of these work. How do I make it work?